# How can show closeable <div> in the top of the page

Tags: html

How can show closeable  in the top of the page like stackoverflow new answers.
im using asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really pretty simple - there's a div, with a control in it (an anchor I imagine) with a click event bound to it which removes the parent item from the DOM. Something like this

```
 <!-- html -->
 <div id="warning"><a href="#" class='close'>[X]</a></div>
```

And then some event goodness:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close').bind('click', function(e) {
         $(this).parent.remove();
    });
});
```

and you're pretty much done. Add salt and CSS to taste.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the notification bar?  If so, there is a nice demo and code snippet here.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/

Comment: It makes me sad that there's a plug-in for something that's LITERALLY 2 lines of code. 3 if you want it to remove itself after X time.

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow uses Javascript with the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) library to create this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few jQuery imlpementations of the effect you looking for:

- [Slide Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)
- [Slide Down](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)
- [Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [Queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

You will have to build on these.